# Spring-Jdbc Template and Prepared statement

Tags: java, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc

Do I need to close Prepared Statement and Connection (jt.getDataSource().getConnection()) when using Spring-Jdbc Template? Or they will be closed by Template mechanizm?

```
public void updateRow() throws SQLException {

        final int i = 100;
        final int y = 2;

        PreparedStatementCreator creator = new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement updateSales = con.prepareStatement(
                "update ignor set ignored_id=? where id=?");
                updateSales.setInt(1, i);
                updateSales.setInt(2, y);
                return updateSales;
            }
        };

        PreparedStatement updateIgnor = creator.createPreparedStatement(jt.getDataSource().getConnection());
        int k = updateIgnor.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("rows updated = " + k);

    }
```

Comment: Are you executing query just once?

Comment: Well, in real application this method can run many times...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the JDBCTemplate does its own PreparedStatement internally, if you just use the .update(String sql, Object ... args) form. Spring, and your database, will manage the compiled query for you, so you don't have to worry about opening, closing, resource protection, etc.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use the `PreparedStatementCreator`, instead of calling the `JdbcTemplate`methods that take an SQL statement as a parameter, you should use the `JdbcTemplate` method that takes your `PreparedStatementCreator` as a parameter.

In your example remove:

```
PreparedStatement updateIgnor = creator.createPreparedStatement(jt.getDataSource().getConnection());
int k = updateIgnor.executeUpdate();
```

and replace it with:

```
int k = jt.update(creator);
```

That way the `JdbcTemplate` will handle the statement and connection resources plus any transaction management and close the resources as needed.